# How to implement same userrole with different set of permissions in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to create such a system in which multiple user can have same user role but different permission.
e.g.

- User 1: as Author can create page as well as add image.
- User 2: as Author can only create page

**I have tried this**: 
 - Added comma separated User Role into UserRole columns.
 - But i think it will not a scalable,long term and right approach.

Please guide me.

Comment: you should have a user permissions table for this. And no, please don't use comma separated roles

Comment: @Lamak Comma separated roles actually makes sense in the context of an ASP app using the `Authorize` attribute, but since we have no idea what OP is doing, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build up a table of permissions

```
Permission_id, Permission_name
1 'Create page'
2 'Add image'
```

Then assign these permissions to each user through a second table user_permissions

```
user_id, permission_id
1 1
1 2
2 1
```

Edit:
or, if you want to build specific roles

Do the same with permissions, but build up additional structure like a table user_role

```
user_role_id, user_role_description
1 "User can create page and add image"
2 "User can add image"
```

And add permissions to these roles through user_role_permissions

```
user_role_id, permission_id
1 1
1 2
2 1
```

And assign these roles to the users with an additional table similar to user_permissions (if you want the user to be able to have multiple roles) or an extra column user_role_id in the user table

Comment: There are probably more ways to do this, depending on what you want to achieve :)